# Google Calendar notifications go to Gmail spam box

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, spam-prevention

I mistakenly marked Google Calendar notification email as a spam, 
so these notification mails go to spam box.
How can I let these emails come to inbox hereafter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Gmail app, go to your Spam folder, highlight one of those notifications, and click the "Not Spam" button. This should tell Gmail to not use the address it came from as spam again.

If you do not have any of those on hand, have one of those notifications sent to you again, and try the above.

Comment: It might take marking several of these as "not spam", and some time, before Gmail "notices".